# Whats the format for adding multiple search paths in Android.mk makefile?

Tags: android, makefile, header, include-path

GNU Makefile uses -I switch. What I know is that I have to go

```
CFLAGS= -I/usr/include/gtk+-3.0 -I/usr/include/gtkmm-3.0
```

How would I add those two search paths in an Android make as CFLAGS

This is the part of the Makefile I need to modify to add search paths

> Android.mk

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := lib_driver_cmd_mt66xx
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libc libcutils
LOCAL_CFLAGS := $(L_CFLAGS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(WPA_SRC_FILE)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(WPA_SUPPL_DIR_INCLUDE)
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

> Why am I asking?

I need to add search paths for missing headers in android source
When I build I get the following error

```
device/orange/klifd/lib_driver_cmd_mt66xx/mediatek_driver_cmd_nl80211.c:12:28: fatal error: driver_nl80211.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
build/core/binary.mk:512: recipe for target '/mnt/workspace/lineage/11.0/out/target/product/klifd/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/lib_driver_cmd_mt66xx_intermediates/mediatek_driver_cmd_nl80211.o' failed
make: *** [/mnt/workspace/lineage/11.0/out/target/product/klifd/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/lib_driver_cmd_mt66xx_intermediates/mediatek_driver_cmd_nl80211.o] Error 1
```

So I want to add the search paths for `driver_nl80211.h` to Android.mk. The headers are in `hardware/libhardware_legacy/include/hardware_legacy`.
What would be the format if I want to add extra paths incase they have dependencies like GNU's `-I/dir1 -I/dir2`

Comment: Did you try using -I/dir1 ? what happend?

Comment: are you in the Android.mk I should go `LOCAL_CFLAGS  := $(L_CFLAGS)  -I/dir1 `